# Activiti JPA support (activiti-spring-boot-starter-jpa) unable to detect generic primary key type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activiti

I'm working on a project in which our JPA Entities inherit *org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable*, which looks as below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractPersistable<PK extends Serializable> implements Persistable<PK> {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private PK id;

    ...
```

And our domain classes are defined as below:

```
public class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    ...
}
```

So, eventually, all our primary keys are Long. However, when I'm trying to start a process instance with a domain object, I'm getting this error:

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Error while evaluating expression: ${reviewer}

  ...

Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Primary key type for JPA-Entity: java.io.Serializable

    at org.activiti.engine.impl.variable.JPAEntityMappings.createId(JPAEntityMappings.java:168)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.variable.JPAEntityMappings.getJPAEntity(JPAEntityMappings.java:120)
   ...
```

So, looks like activiti-spring-boot-starter-jpa won't work when the domain classes inherit from a base class which has generic primary key, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, the only supported ID types are primitives.
There is a comment in the code that goes:

```
<snip>
    Class<?> type = metaData.getIdType();
    // According to JPA-spec all primitive types (and wrappers) are supported, String, util.Date, sql.Date,
    // BigDecimal and BigInteger
</snip>
```

By using a generic, the code is passing through a serializable that is not properly matched.
Seems this would be a relatively easy override in the JPAEntityMappings class.